# How do I get the ID of an object from mongodb database in my react application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am learning by building. I am building a blog management system using Reactjs, Nodejs, Mongodb.
I would like to store some frontend values in the database so that anyone I give admin permission can post, edit and delete such values. These values are website name, sub-name, sidebar bio description, header image and bio image.

This is the code to create the value:

```
//create new frontend paramters into database
router.post("/", async (req, res) =>{
const newFrontendValues = new Frontend(req.body);//we called the    frontend model we created and we used req.body

try{
    const savedFrontendValues = await newFrontendValues.save()//we tried to save the frontend values created
  
    
    res.status(200).json(savedFrontendValues)
}catch(err){
   res.status(500).json(err)
}

});
```

I wrote the code in node to get the values like this after creating them:

```
//get frontend parameters
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) =>{
try{
    const frontend = await Frontend.findById(req.params.id)
    res.status(200).json(frontend)
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
}
})
```

my server api code

```
app.use("/api/frontend", frontend)
```

In react, I wanted to call the _id of the values but I am lost. I really don't know how to go about that.
It is working fine as desired in postman because I can directly implement the value _id.
See attached image
[image]

But in React, I wanted that to be dynamic.

Here is my React code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  const fetchFrontendValue = async () =>{
      const res = await axios.get("/frontend")
      console.log(res.data)
  }
 fetchFrontendValue()
 }, [])
```

How do I add the _id to this

```
axios.get("/frontend")
```

Comment: When you call `fetchFrontendValue` are there route params that have the `id` that you want to fetch data for? How are you tracking which id is the right id for that page/view in the front end?

Comment: One thing to note: the frontend should never know that mongodb is used. It should only be concerned with making HTTP calls to the backend. How those calls are implemented are irrelevant in the React code. The backend is solely responsible for accessing the database and creating a JSON string in the response. This separation of responsibilities helps us humans think more clearly about each system. With that said, the solution here is to be sure to include the id in the response from the nodejs backend.

Comment: To that end, what does `Frontend.findById()` return? What is `findById()`? Is this a function you wrote? If so, please [edit] your question to include it and any other related code.

Comment: I updated the code to show the code that creates the frontend values. Is that what you're asking of?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to look at get request parameters. Usually as a convention, people pass them in the URL. So it would be something like `http://localhost:5000/api/frontend?id=${id}` and on the API side, you'd use `req.body.id` to pass that to the database. There are other ways to do it too, but this is the most common because some old browser drop the parameters attached to a GET request. Here's a link:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: what if the id changes? for instance, admin decides to delete the value

Comment: You should be loading all the IDs first and passing them to the FrontEnd. And when the user requests a specific ID, you'd handle it like in my answer. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider going for a complete solution. On a basic level, you should be following these steps

1. Implement a backend route `/getall` that fetch out all items in DB in this manner

   `await Frontend.find({})`
2. Render the fetched list on frontend side in a way that each item would be a React UI item and as part of each item, you have the buttons for deleting and updating the item data

   `{backendData?.map((item, index)=><SingleItem key={item?._id} data={item} />)}`
3. As each SingleItem has update and delete buttona and also the mongodb ID as part of data, so on clicking update and delete button, you will get the id from the data and call relevant DB Url on backend side